# Angular 2 - Twitter search api - Application-only authentication error 400 on preflight

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter, cors

I try to make a call to twitter search API with the Application-only authentication

But I can't obtain a bearer token following the doc : https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

```
let urlAuth = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token';
let apiKey = encodeURIComponent('xxx');
let apiKeySecret = encodeURIComponent('xxx');
let encoded = btoa(apiKey + ':' + apiKeySecret);
let body = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
let options = {
   headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded
   })
};

this.http.post(urlAuth, body, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('twitter auth', data);
  });
```

this is the network log :

```
Request URL:https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:400 
Remote Address:104.244.42.194:443
```

Is it possible from localhost? from the client?

Answer (score 0):

This is because CORS preflighteed requests ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests )

It seems that event now the Twitter API doesn't support CORS. The only way woould be to make the requests from a backend server.